# Traer datos mediante un select Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy realizando un proyecto en donde por medio de un `select` yo escojo a un desarrollador y me traiga los datos de la base de datos de dicho desarrollador ejemplo (selecciono al desarrollador daniel y me traer su especialidad y horas)
he intentado hacerlo pero lo único que he podido hacer es que me traiga los desarrolladores al select y `setee` el nombre a un `input`. Me podrían decir como puedo hacer para traer esos datos y mostrarlos en los `input` ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de la vista

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que hacer un service al que pasandole la id del desarrollador te devuelva los datos que quieres, y en la vista por javascript/jquery setearlo

```
$("#select").onchange(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "/test.php?id=".$(this).attr("id"), success: function(result){
        $("#input_1").val(result.precio);
        $("#input_2").html(result.especialidad);
    }});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero definiremos una ruta en el archivo `web.php` que nos devuelva el los datos del desarrollador seleccionado, y filtraremos los campos deseados con el método `only`.

```
Route::get('developer/{developer}', function (App\Developer $developer) {
    return $developer->only('name', '...');
});
```

Ahora creamos la lógica del `select`, para que solicite los datos a la ruta que hemos creado y los establezca en los `inputs` deseados. Usaremos el `value` del `select` para establecer el `id` del desarrollador.

Vista blade.

```
<select id="developers">
    @foreach($developers as $developer)
    <option value="{{ $developer->id }}">{{ $developer->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Script para el select.

```
$('#developers').on('change', function() {

    // Usaremos el método 'get' para obtener los 
    // datos del desarrollador mediante ajax.

    $.get(encodeURI('developer/'+ this.value), function(developer) {

        // Con el método 'each' recorremos los datos.

        $.each(developer, function(key, data) {

            // Buscamos un input que tenga el mismo nombre
            // que nuestro campo, y establecemos su valor
            // con los datos del desarrollador.

            $("input[name="+ key +"]").val(data);
        });
    });
})
```