# Llenar un select PHP Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, laravel-5

Tengo esta funcion select que lo que hace es selecionar la tabla del cliente y los seleciona por pais,  en el cual si trae los datos esto en el controlador de Clientes.

```
public function select(){ 
    $data = DB::select('select * from clientes where pais = ?', [51]);
    return view('file/create')->with('data',$data);
}
```

La ruta es la siguiente:

```
Route::get('select', 'ClienteController@select');
```

En la vista tengo algo como esto que es lo que quiero que llene.

```
<div class="selec-grupo">
    <select  selected="selected" name="select" value="">
    <option value="">Selecione un cliente</option>    
</div>
```

si preguntan ya lo realice con un @foreach pero aun asi no se muestra en la vista los datos que quiero. si me pudieran ayudar y si algo no les quedo claro con mucho gusto me pregunta para ver si puedo,  aclararme mejor. 
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Lo has hecho de esta forma? Sustituyendo **valor** y **valor2** por el campo deseado.

```
<select id="developers">
    @foreach($developers as $select)
    <option value="{{ $developer->valor }}">{{ $developer->valor2 }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

[Te dejo más información.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115918/traer-datos-mediante-un-select-laravel)

Comment: si al usar eso me da un error       ErrorException
…\storage\framework\views\1b9ba3b702ae677595640885e61a89744348cff7.php
37 
     <select id="developers">
    <?php $__currentLoopData = $developers; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $select): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
    <option value="<?php echo e($developer->pais); ?>"><?php echo e($developer->name); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
</select> eso se muestra cuando me tira el error

Comment: ¿Y si utilizas esto para obtener los datos?

Route::get('developer/{developer}', function (App\Developer $developer) {
    return $developer->only('name', '...');
});

Comment: no eso tampoco me funciono,  si me pudieras seguir ayudando mira al imprimir el {{dato}} por ejemplo que eso es un echo se cae la pagina no se por que

Comment: ¿Puedes poner los logs?

Comment: [2018-10-25 10:48:09] local.ERROR: Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data' (View: C:\plataforma\resources\views\file\create.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data' (View: C:\\plataforma\
esources\\views\\file\\create.blade.php) at C:\\plataforma\\storage\\framework\\views\\1b9ba3b702ae677595640885e61a89744348cff7.php:27, ErrorException(code: 0): Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data' at C:\plataforma\\storage\\framework\\views\\1b9ba3b702ae677595640885e61a89744348cff7.php:27)

Comment: Veo algo que se me pasó. Trata de imprimirlo con  **$** , de este modo ->  {{$dato}}

Comment: <select>
         @foreach($data as $dt) 
         <option value="{{$dt->pais}}">{{$dt->nombre}}</option>
         @endforeach
         </select> asi ?

Comment: Exacto. O imprime cualquier valor, pero incluye $

Comment: Htopete se sigue callendo         <select>
         <?php $__currentLoopData = $data; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $dt): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?> 
         <option value="<?php echo e($dt->pais); ?>"><?php echo e($dt->nombre); ?></option>
         <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
         </select> me sale de esa manera cuando se cae en la pagina

Comment: <select id="developers">
    @foreach($developers as $data)
    <option value="{{ $developer->valor }}">{{ $developer->valor2 }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

Comment: revienta el programa,  ya no se que mas hacerle,  talvez alguna manera de usar ajax y que se conecte al  controller

Comment: Te voy a dejar un enlace, me dices si te fue de ayuda. 
[Aquí](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-dynamic-dependant-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-example-part-2example.html)